# Why I am getting an error while reading a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, pycharm

I'm trying to open a csv file so that I can compare my lottery numbers (six randomly generated integers from 1 to 54) to the previous winning numbers from 1992 to 2017 which is what the csv file contains.

```
import random

import csv

six_random_int =[random.randint(1,54),random.randint(1,54),random.randint(1,54),random.randint(1,54),random.randint(1,54),random.randint(1,54)]

print('Your lotto ticket is ',six_random_int)

with open('lottotexas.csv','r') as f:  #This is where the error is occurring
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
with open('lottotexas.csv','r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lottotexas.csv'.
```

I have the csv file downloaded on my computer but i don't know where to go from there so that my python program can find the csv file.

Comment: python will try to open the file from the current working directory, you have to provide the fullpath to the file

Comment: In other words, it's probably looking for the CSV in the same directory that your script is in. Having the file in "downloads" won't help if your python script isn't also in that folder. If they're in different folders, you'll either neet to give the absolute path or relative path to the file.

Comment: for any error, you better to google it before asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite clear from the `error` that you are getting:

```
with open('lottotexas.csv','r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lottotexas.csv'.
```

That Python cannot find the file `'lottotexas.csv'`.

The way Python will try to `open` the file, is to look in the current `directory` of the `.py` `file` for that `filename` - unless you have given a full `file path`. If you give a full `path` to the `file`, then Python will open the `file` from that location.

Nevertheless, the way that you have written this program, Python is trying to find a `file` named: `lottotexas.csv` in the same `directory` as the Python `file` - and there is no `file` named that! - hence the `error`: `FileNotFoundError`!

Comment: Thanks! Now that I have the python file and the csv file in the same directory i can read the csv file

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full path of the file. You must have python executing in the same folder where your file is placed.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy and paste the file in the same path (folder/directory/place) where u have your python program.
And run your program again.
If the problem persists then check for file permission.